# Extract year from a text field containing a date in SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

I have dates stored in my database with this format (stored in plain text)

```
2017-07-15 19:25:07-0400
```

Now I would like to retrieve the year for a particular record by doing this

```
select strftime('%Y', '2017-07-15 19:25:07-0400' ) from T1
```

However this always returns null because of the time zone. If I remove the time zone it works ok. Any ideas?

Comment: That is not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

Answer (score 2):

If it is stored as text, in that format, use [`substr(column, 1, 4)`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr).

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer... In order parts of my program I need to retrieve seconds and other stuff. Not sure if I would like to go in that direction, but maybe it's the only way.